# How to convert stock data from xts object to ts object

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I used quantmod to download stock data from yahoo finance. Here msft is a xts object.

```
library(quantmod)
library(forecast)
library(xts)
library(zoo)
start <- as.Date('2018-01-01')
end <- as.Date('2018-08-14')
getSymbols('MSFT', src='yahoo', from=start, to=end)
msft <- MSFT[, 'MSFT.Adjusted']
```

I'm trying to convert xts object to ts object. Below is what I did. My result is kind of weird. What frequency should I put in this case? The stock data are daily data (weekdays only). Thanks a lot for help.

```
ts(msft, start=c(2018,1,1), frequency = 365)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `as.timeSeries.xts` from the `xts` library.

```
msft <- as.timeSeries.xts(MSFT)
str(as.timeSeries.xts(msft))
plot(msft)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
msft1<- as.data.frame(msft) #converting it to Data frame 
rownames(msft1) <- NULL #Nullify all the rownames 

timeseries<-ts(msft1, start=c(2018,1,1), frequency = 365) #convert it into a ts object
plot(timeseries) ## Plot to verify the time series
```

you can select weekdays from the below code

```
# install.packages('timeDate')
require(timeDate)

# A ’timeDate’ Sequence
tS <- timeSequence(as.Date("1991/1/4"), as.Date("2010/3/1"))
tS

# Subset weekdays
tW <- tS[isWeekday(tS)]; tW
dayOfWeek(tW)
```

Comment: thanks. But I was wondering stock data is on weekdays. setting the frequency as 356 will mess up the time, right? I'm confused what I should do...

Comment: @zesla i have  updated the code with how to take only weekdays from the ts, please have a look